# Read-only variable when assigning object to variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a variable named picture that is taking in a thumbnail that is an address for a picture. I want to use that as the `src` path for my `img` tag. How do I accomplish this? From what i'm understanding is React generates `render()` first and then `componentDidMount()`, but my code is returning `Cannot set property 'src' of null`.

**Update**
I changed the code based off suggested comments. I loaded the state in my constructor so that gets defined before everything else. But now it says `picture" is read-only` which is where `-->` is

**Code**

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.getVideos();
    const picture = {};
    this.props.getVideos();
    if (this.props.videos == null) {
      console.log("It's null");
    } else {
      const videos = this.props.videos.video.map(video => {
        <h5 key={video._id}>{video.thumbnail}</h5>;
   -->     picture = video.thumbnail;
      });
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(picture);
  }
```

**Snippet of return in render**

```
 <div className="explore">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="row__inner">
            <div className="tile">
              <div className="tile__media">
                <img className="tile__img" id="thumbnail" src={picture} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className="tile__details">
                <div className="tile__title">
                  <h5>Impact Dallas</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Update**
I changed the code based off suggested comments. I loaded the state in my constructor so that gets defined before everything else. But now it says `picture" is read-only` which is where `-->` is

Comment: Why dont you just take it from state.

Comment: Why don't you just use `<img className="tile__img" id="thumbnail" src={this.state.picture} alt="" />` ?

Comment: I changed it based off of your good suggestions. But any idea why i'd be getting picture is read only?

Comment: `const picture = {}` and `picture = video.thumbnail` make no sense - it'll break.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. I need to set the video.thumbnail to a state and then call that state. Let me try that.